# TilesContainer not initialized

Tags: struts2, tiles, websphere-8

During JSP rendering I am getting the error saying that unable to initialized tile container.
However i am able to render the normal JSP but if i use tile specific tag get the error.

I am using 
WAS 8.5
eclipse Kepler
Java 7.0
All the necessary jars are present in my lib folder.

My JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="ToolbarBody">
<tiles:putAttribute name="documentTitle" value="findUser" type="string"></tiles:putAttribute>
<tiles:putAttribute name="bodyarea" value="/WEB-INF/content/findUser_body.jsp" type="page"></tiles:putAttribute>
<tiles:putAttribute name="menuarea" value="/WEB-INF/content/menu.jsp" type="page"></tiles:putAttribute>
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

Logs:

```
000000df webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: TilesContainer not initialized]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: TilesContainer not initialized
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:626)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:656)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1301)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:127)
       at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.GenericResponseWrapper.sendError(GenericResponseWrapper.java:104)
       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:914)
       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
       at com.keane.util.FunctionAuditFilter.doFilter(FunctionAuditFilter.java:172)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
       at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:95)
       at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Web.xml tiles mapping

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
              org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
              /WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: Which S2 version? Which tiles version? Show your web.xml.

Comment: <servlet>
     <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>
           org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
         </param-name>
         <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml
         </param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

Comment: Struts and Tiles integration wired via the plugin.

Comment: Any solution for that, or i am missing somthing in Websphere setup?

Comment: Try with `StrutsTilesListener`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to get some idea about your error.

1. Incorrect / Missing DTD reference in the tiles-defs.xml
2. Incorrect / Missing XML Elements in the tiles-defs.xml
3. Missing retrotranslator-runtime-n.n.n.jar in WEB-INF/lib

   -Sandeep Seshan's Log-

[More Details](http://sandeepseshan.blogspot.com/2008/06/apache-tiles-error-tilescontainer-not.html)